# What are those class extensions for the Cartesian class for?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, monoids

The [`Cartesian`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:Cartesian) class from the [`constrained-category`](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/constrained-categories) project is for categories, products of objects in which are objects in the same category yet again.

I wonder about the classes `Cartesian` *extends*:

```
class ( Category k                                      {- 1 -}
      , Monoid (UnitObject k)                           {- 2 -}
      , Object k (UnitObject k)                         {- 3 -}
      -- , PairObject k (UnitObject k) (UnitObject k)   {- 4 -}
      -- , Object k (UnitObject k,UnitObject k)         {- 5 -}
      ) => Cartesian k where
...
```

Points `1` and `3` are pretty straightforward:

- 1: `Cartesian` extends `Category`.
- 3: The `UnitObject k` shall indeed be an object in `k`.

Other points confuse me:

- 2: Why do we want `UnitObject k` to be a `Monoid`? A proper unit is indeed a monoid (`() <> () = ()` and `mempty = ()`; the same goes for all other units as there exists only one unit modula the isomorphisms like `unitType2Id ~() = id`), but it is a necessary condition, not a sufficient one. Why don't we implement some class like:

  ```
  class ProperUnit u where
      toUnitType :: u -> ()
      fromUnitType :: () -> u
  ```

  With the following law: `fromUnitType . toUnitType = id`.
  I reckon *extending* neither `Monoid`, nor the `ProperUnit` classes to add extra features to the code, simply making it more idiomatic. Or am I wrong?
- 4: This one is commented out. Why so? What did we need the pair of two units for in the first place? Isn't it as good as a regular unit? They are clearly isomorphic.
- 5: This one is commented out once again. Why so? And why did we need such a pair to be an object in the category? Isn't this condition weaker than the previous one?<sup>**1**</sup> The `PairObject` type institutes extra restrictions concerning pairs. If such a pair is, in fact, an object in the category, it still doesn't necessarily satisfy the `PairObject` restriction, in which case we can't use it at all.

Can someone, please explain the logic behind these 3 points.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> As Bartosz Milewski pointed out, `PairObject` (currently renamed into [`PairObjects`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:PairObjects)) and [`ObjectPair`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:ObjectPair) are different restrictions, the latter being more strict, guaranteeing that we make up pairs of actual *"tensorable"* objects in a category, where such a pair exists as an object. In fact, points `1`, `3`, `4` and `5` are equivalent to `ObjectPair k (UnitObject k) (UnitObject k)`. Still, I do not quite understand why we entertain such a condition (leaving it commented out).

Comment: Very interesting. I initially thought the commented constraints might be legacy code, but a quick look at the [git history](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/constrained-categories/commit/e923db98dfc64108facd880e2c2ba491d68931d6) shows that they were actually that way to begin with. Good question.

Comment: In a monoidal category a tensor product is defined for every pair of objects. Here the product is defined only if objects `a` and `b` satisfy a set of constraints called `ObjectPair`. They have to be both objects in the subcategory we're defining, they have to be 'tensorable' (satisfy `PairObjects`), and the pair `(a, b)` has to be an object. So it's not automatic that you can take a tensor product of `UnitObject` with itself, much less that it's a `Monoid`.

Comment: @BartoszMilewski sure, but why do we need those features?

Answer (score 2):

Like Bartosz Milewski commented: strictly speaking none of this should be necessary. Mathematically, you'd just once define what are the objects of your category and the unit, and that all tensor products are too, and `((),a) ≡ a` etc., and `PairObject` is superfluous.

The problem is... well, pragmatism and Haskell. Like, it's well known that a proper equality between `((a,b),c)` and `(a,(b,c))` is right out of the window. But also from a practical development perspective you don't necessarily want to think in this deductive mathematical way. I found it to be more practical to keep the `Category` class simple and then add some ad-hoc constraints to the more specialised classes, rather than demanding everything to hold as mathematically as possible right from the start. (When implementing these constraints right in `Object`, I found myself having to carry around more type information in GADT fields and explicitly unpacking tuples again, which the `PairObject` can often supplant without awkward value-level pattern matching.)

Specifically, some `Type->Type->Type`s can easily be made an instance of `Category`, with only a light constraint to implement `id`, but require more complicated machinery for e.g. `***`. In this case, you're strictly speaking working with two different categories: the one described by the `Category` instance, and a smaller subcategory of it that's cartesian monoidal. Or even a whole family of categories, each with a different `PairObject`-connected class of objects.

As to why `Monoid`: as you've guessed, it's not *really* the right class for the task, but it does the job and is widespread. Your `ProperUnit` class wouldn't give you any more tooling, as the `toUnitType` method is always trivial and `fromUnitType ≡ const mempty`. I believe what you're actually thinking about here is

```
class Monoid a => Singleton a where
  hasOnlyUnit :: a -> {Proof that a==mempty}
```

but that's awkward to do without dependent types. I'm also not sure whether it would actually buy us anything.

Unfortunately the name `Monoid` makes it a bit of a red herring in this context.

The “job” it solves, concretely, is concerned with *global elements*, in particular when using the [`Agent`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:HasAgent) types for encoding categorical composition chains into lambda expressions – all of it in the footsteps of Conal Elliot's work on hardware compilation etc., but as a Haskell library.

I shuffled around what's the best place for putting the various constraints a couple of times, and the commented-out `PairObject k (UnitObject k) (UnitObject k)` constraints are an artifact of that: these constraints should morally hold, but what I found was that explicitly requiring them there causes more problems when defining instances, than it solves when using them.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to dig into the details of my library, and sorry the answer is again just “after some trial and error, I found this particular setup to work for my applications”.

Comment: Also remember I'm open to suggestions to change the library.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you, please give an idea what dependent types are and how they would help us implement the `Singleton` class? I’ve never come across dependent types.